# Send images to android client

Tags: android, python, image, client-server

I have an Server written in Python and a client written in Java(android),
I want to send lots of photos one by one to the client, and the client should present in like video (not need to be good video, but you need to see changes)..
The only way that I found that somehow it can works is by send image and replace the ImageView in the Andoird client.. 
someone knows a way to do what Im try to do?
thanks

Comment: Could you provide a little more information. For example show what you have tried so far for your server and client. How are you connecting them? TCP, internet, etc

Comment: until now, i have nothing, i dont know how to start.
basicly they will conect with sockets (UDP or TCP i dont care)

Comment: I don't know if this might be of any help to you, but some time ago I wanted to test the exact same thing out. I used java for both client and server. I had a DNS web address that directs web traffic to my home pc. The android would get the IP address from the web address and request a random image off my PC. Look here for the full code: http://wlgfx.com/programming/tcp-android-client-and-server-code/

Comment: I would start with the ImageView and ignore the server for the moment. Why don't you try to show a simple activity with an ImageView and change the image after some time or when the user clicks a button? You probably do not need to replace the view itself, but just give it a different picture. Maybe have a look at the setImageBitmap and setImageDrawable methods of ImageView

Comment: what exactly is bitmap? can i send it from python to android?